# Get Current loggedIn UserID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the `Current` loggedin UserID of the user without using `Membership` How can I achieve that ?

Here is my code

```
 string CurrentlyLoggedInUser = Session["User"].ToString(); // get the userId for username and compare
        string userId = CurrentlyLoggedInUser; // assign the userid here and check ok
        if (Id == userId)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You cannot delete yourself');window.location ='AdduserProfile.aspx';", true);
            return;
        }
```

But I am not getting the `ID`. Please help

Values from Session

```
 if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "0") //SuperAdmin
            {
                Session["UserType"] = "0";
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "1") // Admin
            {
                Session["UserType"] = "1";
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
            else if (dt.Rows[0]["usertype"].ToString() == "2") // User
            {
                Session["UserType"] = "2";
                Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("csrdashboards.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you use Membership

Comment: Don't store user information in session and if this is `asp.net`, why not use the [Membership provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @DGibbs: got it, Now what is the solution to get the current loggedin user `ID`

Comment: If you want to load the `ID` from Session you first have to put it there!  Right now you are writing the value of a column named `username` to `Session["User"]`.  So a) is this an `Id` and b) is there anything in your data source?

Comment: Perhaps using `User.Identity.Name`...? Must be empty value when anonymous authentication is enabled on IIS. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @PhilipPittle: a) No it is not an `ID`.  b) Nothing related to `User` is in datasource.

Comment: If nothing's in the datasource, it's hardly surprising you're not able to find the ID in your session. You can't possibly have put it there if you didn't find it in the datasource in the first place.

Comment: @RahulSutar In that case, your first piece of code makes no sense. If `Session["user"]` doesn't hold the `ID` of the logged in user, why are you checking it against `Id`?

Comment: @DGibbs: I have `Id`, `username`,`password`,`usertype` in my usertable. So what to check

Comment: @RahulSutar Please tell me you aren't storing the `password` in session too? If you have access to `Id` in your datatable, why aren't you retrieving that instead of `"username"`? Do you have a `User` type? Storing all of these individual values in session would be difficult to manage, storing one `User` in session is much simpler.

Comment: @DGibbs: I am not storing `password` in session. So can I use like this `string CurrentlyLoggedInUser = Session["Id"].ToString();` i m bit confused

Comment: @RahulSutar You need to actually store the `Id` in session before doing that. Read the `Id` out of your datatable/datarow into the session value. You've done this for the other values...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70217/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-dgibbs).

Comment: @DGibbs: I wrote like this: `string CurrentlyLoggedInUser = Session["Id"].ToString();` and got error as . Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @RahulSutar You aren't listening. You need to populate the session value first. e.g. `Session["Id"] = id;` etc... As others have pointed out, your approach to this problem is a bad idea. Use the `Membership Provider`. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the Current loggedin UserID of the user without using
>   Membership How can I achieve that ?

Don't.

Look, I know that Membership isn't a shining example of the very best in API design. I know there are things that I personally would have done differently, as would many others, and there can be a strong temptation to roll your own membership API.

But if you're not 100% confident of your ability to do a better job, don't even try. Security infrastructure is too important and too easy to get wrong, and there's a dangerously high likelihood that you'll get something wrong and leave your site vulnerable.

I don't want to put anybody down, but looking at the quality of the code you've posted (code duplication, unnecessary assignments, multiple dictionary lookups, unnecessary-looking conversions to string all over the place) and some of the statements you're making (about having a "password" field in your database with no mention of hashing), you are not yet at the level of ability required for this, and you're heading for disaster.

"How do I...?" is the wrong question here. "Should I...?" is the first question you should ask, and I'm afraid the answer is no. Use Membership, it's not perfect but it's going to be a lot more secure and robust than anything you come up with yourself.

Comment: For the record, I know it was stated in the question - I *quoted* the question. I still think you're heading down a dangerous path, but it doesn't seem that you're likely to be persuaded.